# SQL unique combination on groupname and subname

Tags: mysql

I want unique combination on `groupname` and `subname` from a table like below. Could anyone help with a query?

The table has `groupname` and `subname`:

```
Groupname Subname
a          100
a          130 
a1         120
a1         100
b          140
b          120
c          130
```

The result should be like `a 100` and `a1 120`. But I don't want the same group name and subname twice in result list.

Comment: `select distinct ...`

Comment: i have tried select distinct groupname , subname from table where groupname in (select distinct groupname in tablename); but this gives groupname duplicates

Comment: what is your expected result? I dont see any duplicates for `{groupname, subname}`

Comment: well, with the dataset we have - i get the result as  a 100 , a 130, a1 120.. i need the groupname and  the subname to be just once in the list. once 'a' is listed with subname, then choose diff groupname and subname.

Comment: please edit your question to include the desire output.

Comment: SQL> select distinct _group, _subtype from _group_members;
GROUP    SUB
---------- -----------
B                 BES
B                 CR1
B                 CR2
B137 group 73C
B137-300w  73C
B147 group 746
B157 group 752
B157 group 753
B157 group 75W
C                 737
C                 738
C                 73C
C                 73W

 There are duplicate subnames(73C) from different Groupname(B and C). Hence i want groupname and subname combination unique where the subname is not in another Group.

Answer (score 0):

if you do the following: select distinct * from tablename you get this:

"Groupname"    "Subname"
 "a"             "130"
 "a1"            "120"
 "a1"            "100"
 "b"             "140"
 "a"             "100"
 "b"             "120"
 "c"             "130"

Now if you do this instead: select groupname, subname from tablename 
group by groupname

"groupname" "subname"
"a"          "130"
"a1"         "120"
"b"          "140"
"c"          "130"

and if you do this instead: select groupname, subname from tablename 
group by subname

groupname   subname
"a1"        "100"
"a1"        "120"
"a"         "130"
"b"         "140"

Comment: Thanks, my desired output is 2nd in your Answer. But I've tried all the distinct and groupby options already and couldnt succeed. SQL> select distinct _group, _subtype from _group_members group by _group;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression